# Как отловить обрезан ли текст с использованием CSS свойств overflow: hidden и text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Пожалуйста, подскажите, можем ли мы как то отловить наложено ли на текст обрезание в три точки?
В чем задумка: у меня есть текстовое поле, в которое прокидываю текст, если текст занимает более трех строк, то обрезаю его с помощью стилей в три строки. Мне необходимо скрывать кнопку еще если текст не занимает более трех строк и на нем не висит text-overflow и показывать в обратном случае, а при нажатии на нее убирать стили обрезающие текст и показывать его целиком, при этом скрывая кнопку.

Возможно в properties элемента мы можем как-то обратиться к какому-либо параментру являющимся индикатором того, что часть текста скрыта.

```css
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">{{ description }}</p>
<button *ngIf="buttonVisible">Еще</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можем. Как-то так (:

```js
function isEllipsisActive(e) {
  return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}

console.log( isEllipsisActive(small) );
console.log( isEllipsisActive(big) );

// пример обработки
if(isEllipsisActive(big)) {
  big.style.border = '1px solid red'
}
```

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;

  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="small">
  <span>Мало текста</span>
</div>
<div id="big">
  <span>Очень много разных букв</span>
</div>
```

```js
const big = document.querySelectorAll('.big')

const isEllipsisActive = e => e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth;
big.forEach(e => isEllipsisActive(e) ? e.style.border = '1px solid red' : false)
```

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">Мало текста</div>
<div class="big">Очень много разных букв</div>

<div class="big">Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень много разных букв</div>
```